# When was libc++ introduced in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, libc++, xcode10

The release notes for Xcode 10 beta 2 say:

> Building with libstdc++ was deprecated with Xcode 8 and is not supported in Xcode 10 when targeting iOS. C++ projects must now migrate to libc++ and are recommended to set a deployment target of iOS 7 or later.

We're currently supporting iOS 6, so the question is what will happen if we switch to libc++ instead of libstdc++. From Apple's wording (setting the deployment target to iOS 7 is only *recommended*, not required) it seems iOS 6 has libc++, but I've not been able to find any documentation about this.

From the wording it also seems that there might be problems with libc++ on iOS 6, but again, no other documentation, so the second question is what kind of problems could that be? Is there anyone who tried libc++ on iOS 6 years ago who would know/remember anything?

Comment: Supporting iOS 6…why do management make developers suffer like that?!?

Comment: @AshleyMills: It's not impossible to bump it, but having a good reason would help a lot (something along the lines of "libc++ is completely broken on iOS 6" would probably do it, but wasn't able to google up anything about it).

Comment: Is this good enough reason? https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Comment: Sometimes you just need to wave goodbye…

Comment: @Desdenova: no, we have many customers who use enterprise deployment, those tend to stick more to older iOS versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libc++ was introduced with iOS 5.0: http://deltaorange.com/2012/11/21/c-compatibility-on-ios-less-5/